# How to query for distinct groups of entities which are joined via a self-referential many-to-many table?

Tags: sql, django, data-modeling

Trying to figure out how to query for distinct groups of entities which are joined via a self-referential many-to-many table. Been poking at it all afternoon, thought I'd ask here to see if anyone else had some ideas.

For example, a Person has a group of friends, and these groups are exclusive (i.e. no overlaps between groups -- a bunch of cliques, if you will). The table structure might look something like this:

```
person
| id | name |
| 1  | bob  |
| 2  | frank |
| 3  | chuck |
| 4  | nancy |
| 5  | alice |
| 6  | sally |

cliques
| from_person_id | to_person_id |
|       1        |      2       |
|       1        |      3       |
|       2        |      1       |
|       2        |      3       |
|       3        |      1       |
|       3        |      2       |
|       4        |      5       |
|       4        |      6       |
|       5        |      4       |
|       5        |      6       |
|       6        |      4       |
|       6        |      5       |
```

(Bob is friends with Frank and Chuck, Frank is friends with Bob and Chuck, Chuck is friends with Bob and Frank, etc.)

I can get a bunch of sets which relate to each Person's friends, but can't figure out how to boil it down. Ultimately, what I'd really like is a query that returns distinct sets of clique members, e.g.

```
| cliques |
| 1, 2, 3 |
| 4, 5, 6 |
```

But, of course, SQL doesn't work that way unless I use something like group_concat (MySQL) or array_agg (PostgreSQL). I'm not strictly opposed to that approach, but I'd prefer to avoid introducing backend-specific implementation (I'm actually using Django's ORM, but didn't want to distract with those details).

My questions are:

- Am I barking up the wrong tree with trying to model things this way?
- Is there a way to assemble distinct cliques without resorting to iteration out in the calling code? I'm not asking to have a single row per clique, because that requires db-specific aggregation, but maybe a generated id-per-clique and a set of (clique_id, member_id) tuples that I can then assemble in the calling code?

Comment: You need for resort to iteration in the calling code.  You are trying to find something called either connected subgraphs or fully connected subgraphs (your example is not clear).  This problem requires walking through the graph.  Although possible with recursive CTEs, SQL may not be the best language for expressing this .

Comment: Amusingly (to me), I am realizing that this question looks like an attempt to get SO to do my CS homework. I swear, it's not! There are some gaps in my CS education (out of school for 15 years now), and after a weekend of reading about this I'm realizing that I've stumbled upon a pretty well-known CS problem rooted in basic graph theory (which I guess I skipped). So it's been an interesting and edifying weekend! I will post whatever solution I come up with, for posterity. I am guessing that I will probably wind up with something based on Bron-Kerbosch implemented in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for connected subgraphs, here is an approach.

You can characterize a connected subgraph by the minimum id of any node in it.

Start with a table to store the subgraph ids, something like:

```
create table subgraphids (
     personid int,
     subgraphid int
);
```

Initialize it:

```
insert into subgraphids(personid, subgraphid)
    select personid, min(subgraphid)
    from (select from_person_id as personid,
                 least(from_person_id, to_person_id) as subgraphid
          from cliques
          union all
          select to_person_id, least(from_person_id, to_person_id)
          from cliques
         ) t
    group by personid;
```

Now you have tentative subgraphids.  To update them, you use a sort-of-similar query:

```
update subgraphid
    set subgraphid = (select min(s.subgraphid)
                      from cliques c join
                           subgraphid s
                           on c.from_person_id = s.personid or
                              c.to_person_id = s.personid
                      where subgraphid.personid = clique.from_person_id or
                            subgraphid.personid = click.to_person_id
                     );
```

Repeat this until no rows are updated.  You can check for that condition explicitly:

```
select count(*)
from subgraphid
where subgraphid > (select min(s.subgraphid)
                    from cliques c join
                         subgraphid s
                         on c.from_person_id = s.personid or
                            c.to_person_id = s.personid
                    where subgraphid.personid = clique.from_person_id or
                          subgraphid.personid = click.to_person_id
                   );
```

This will find connected subgraphs in your original graph.  The iteration needs to take place outside of SQL, in the calling code.

Comment: Accepting this answer, because it describes how one might search for connected subgraphs using SQL. In the end, however, I decided to do the search in python using NetworkX's find_cliques(). I have to touch all of the table rows to search anyhow, so this isn't really any worse performance-wise than trying to do it inside the DB.